# How to read a textBox's Text in another window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a textBox, `textBoxQuery`, in window `QueryWindow`.

I need to access `textBoxQuery`'s `Text` in another window, `MainWindow`.

I have the following accessor in `QueryWindow`:

```
public string QueryString
{
    get { return textBoxQuery.Text; }
    set { textBoxQuery.Text = value; }
}
```

And I attempt to use it in `MainWindow`:

```
cmdLine += QueryString;
```

However, I am thrown a `CS0120` error. "An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property."

I have also attempted to implement the following method in `QueryWindow`:

```
public string queryString()
{
    return textBoxQuery.Text;
}
```

Then using the following in `MainWindow`:

```
cmdLine += QueryWindow.queryString();
```

But none of the above worked.

I have searched through Google, but none of the solutions I found seemed to work. What is the correct way of accessing a control's properties from another window/class?

Comment: You are missing a huge lesson on Object oriented programming. I would start by reading a book first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh!
The assessor is used to access an instance of a class (an object) of type `QueryWindow`!
Basicly, you could create a bunch of query windows (each would be their own instance) by doing this:

```
QueryWindow myQueryWindow1 = new QueryWindow();
myQueryWindow1.show()
QueryWindow myQueryWindow2 = new QueryWindow();
myQueryWindow2.show()
// Note, the shows are only needed to make instances visible to the user.
```

For as long as you have the reference to `myQueryWindow1` or `myQueryWindow2`, you can use an acessor to get the state of the **instance**:

```
string myString = myQueryWindow1.queryString();
```

So `QueryWindow.queryString()` wouldn't work, because there is no way for the program to tell which instance of QueryWindow you want!

Hope this helps!